# using PXDatabase.Delete to remove all row in a Custom table

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to use PXDatabase.Delete to remove specific row(s) in a Custom table or even just to get it to fire off. Here is the code that I am trying to get running:

```
PXDatabase.Delete<SSINHoldRule>(
                        new PXDataFieldRestrict<SSINHoldRule.inventoryID>(18));
```

When I watch SQL profiler for this code to get executed, nothing shows up in the SQL profiler which means that this code is not hitting the database. I have different variations of the above code but to avail. Any help would be appreciated. I am running this code via the TestSDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this would be considered direct DB manipulation, which is frowned upon by Acumatica (Documented within Acumatica certification guidelines) and should be used as a last resort. Is there a reason this is not working with general DAC record manipulation? We want to assess using that before considering a more brute force methods such as PXDatabase.Delete.

Comment: So I believe that I figured out my problem. I am doing this from the TestSDK test project and that project does not know  about the database it is just a way to test the front end of Acumatica. Thanks for your response though.